# Sonar Lint not in sync with server rules

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarlint

Sonar Lint 2.0, It's connected to my own Sonar Qube server with no issues reported by the plugin.
The issue is that it is not in sync with my server rules. Found those mentioned in the doc for Java but they also seemed not to be all.  I wonder if these java rule list are used only when it's not connected to any server only.

Does it have a restriction of what rules to use or synchronize when using a remote server?

What exactly we can do to make it synch if it is possible.

```
Plateform: Java
SonarQube Server: Version 5.6+
Sonar Lint: Version 2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is that:**

1. SonarQube Server supports external plugins like PMD, FindBug, and CheckStyle.
2. SonarLint management has decided **not** to support any external plugin, so you have only support of Sonar bug rules here.

**Solution:**

What we can do is that we can **export** the bug rules file from SonaQube Server and **link** it with the installed external plugins (PMD, FindBug, CheckStyle) so they can prompt you issues which Sonarlint is not able to show alone.