# Sonar Lint Eclipse Issue

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Neon and SonarQube 5.6.6(LTS). I've install sonarLint version 3.1.0. Following are my question.

1. In SonarLint whether there is an option to analyze the entire project? I can't able to find such option.
2. The issue showing  in Eclipse reported by sonar lint is different from reported on server. When I'm wantedly creating the sonar issues(based on the rule) in eclipse but SonarLint is not recognizing . why?
3. From Eclipse I've made the connection to the SonarQube server and the connection was success, Whether it is using the activated quality profile rule?
4. After resolving the issues, how the issues will be reflected to the sonarQube server ? In case of Maven whether I need to add the sonar properties and  sonar-maven plugin and trigger the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Select your project and in Eclipse's *Quick Access*, select *Analyze - Analyze with SonarLint*. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to this action by going to *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys*.

**2.** It seems as if you are not running in connected mode. Connecting a SonarQube server is not enough, you also have to bind individual projects. To do this, right click on your project in Eclipse, and select *SonarLint -> Bind to a SonarQube project...* Search for the name of your project on the server by typing in the box under SonarQube project, as show in the following screenshot:

[image: SonarQube binding]

Once connected, a SonarQube symbol should appear on your project's icon in Eclipse.

**3.** Once connected, the quality profile of your SonarQube server project will be used.

**4.** SonarLint only provides on the fly feedback, but does not trigger any analysis server side. Personally I have a `clean verify sonar:sonar` Maven run configuration for my projects, and run it every now and again within Eclipse.

---

I recommend reading the [SonarLint documentation](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Pyves now I can able to do.

Comment: From the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361803/sonar-lint-not-in-sync-with-server-rules/43536655" i understood that sonarlint will not show the issues for (pmd, checkstyle and findbug) and need to install the plugin in the eclipse.Can you please provide the steps how to integrate the rules(pmd, checkstyle and findbug) with eclipse. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use those specific plugins, so I don't really know how to integrate their rules with Eclipse, if possible at all. Maybe try looking into the preferences of those plugins, their documentation, or try asking a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend either to change your version or to be sure which configuration really applies to your machine. I had  similar problem when i tried to associate my local project with the project name on Sonarqube Server . I was using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) with Sonarlint version 4.0 . I uninstalled it(sonarlint) and installed the Sonarlint 3.6 version. After this i could associate my project with Sonarqube Server.
Hope it Helps the main question.