# SonarLint is not showing the issues for the external plugin (PMD,FindBug,CheckStyle)

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm using the SonarLint version as 3.1.0 in eclipse Neon. And SonarQube version as 5.6.6.

While analyzing the issue for the project, it is noticed that it is not showing the issues for the external plugin (PMD,FindBug,CheckStyle).

From the [Sonar Lint not in sync with server rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361803/sonar-lint-not-in-sync-with-server-rules/43536655) link I understood that the sonarLint will not support to the external plugin. Is there any idea of supporting the external plugin in the future release of SonarLint version?

Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Even the latest version of SonarLint does not support the external plugins(pmd,findbugs,checkstyle etc).It only uses the squid rules in the sonarqube which are written by **modifying and optimising the external plugin rules**.

The reason why SonarLint doesn't support external plugins is that **pmd,findbugs analyses code in different manners** pmd compares the code by making a **syntax tree** and findbugs need **byte code** to analyse.So this **takes up a lot of time**.

To analyse in a **faster and efficient manner** the sonarlint **only supports 
squid rules from sonar server**.so **i don't think** there will be an update 
to support external plugins like pmd,findbugs etc.Because most of the external plugin rules have **rewritten in an optimised manner** in SonarQube.